# Floating Action Button and design library inflation error

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-theme, floating-action-button, android-inflate

I'm using design support library

```
defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        ...
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    ...
}
```

when I'm adding FloatingActionButton

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:tint="#fff"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
    app:backgroundTint="#b3000000"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

to one of my layouts I get this error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.
```

Here's my main activity (`it has navigation drawer`)

```
public class MapNavActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

I know it should work if I change `AppCompatActivity` to `Activity`

However this don't work for me. Here's the activity defined on manifest file

```
<activity
    android:name=".MapNavActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_map_nav"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarMain" />
```

and here's the theme in styles.xml file

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBarMain" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

I'm stuck with this problem almost 5 hours. Does anyone know how to solve this?

EDIT manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="rojus.zvyjybos.com.zvejybosrojus2">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.compass" />

    <application
        android:name=".start.App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".start.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MapNavActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_map_nav"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarMain" />
        <activity
            android:name=".menu_activities.LakeDetailActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarMain" />
        <activity
            android:name=".menu_activities.FishActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarMain" />
        <activity
            android:name=".menu_activities.BitesActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarMain" />
        <activity
            android:name=".menu_activities.FishingMethodsActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarMain" />
        <activity
            android:name=".fragments.MyFishingPlanDetailList"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarMain" />
        <activity
            android:name=".menu_activities.DetailPlaceActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarMain" />
        <activity android:name=".augumented_reality.AugumentedActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".start.MainMenu"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarMain" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I will also add full exception

```
Process: rojus.zvyjybos.com.zvejybosrojus2, PID: 26070
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{rojus.zvyjybos.com.zvejybosrojus2/rojus.zvyjybos.com.zvejybosrojus2.MapNavActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2441)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:162)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5431)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:914)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:707)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:916)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
   at rojus.zvyjybos.com.zvejybosrojus2.map.MapFragment.customMapView(MapFragment.java:416)
   at rojus.zvyjybos.com.zvejybosrojus2.map.MapFragment.onViewCreated(MapFragment.java:322)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:339)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:601)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1236)
   at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6068)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2342)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2441) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:162) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5431) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:914) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:707) 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:916) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
   at rojus.zvyjybos.com.zvejybosrojus2.map.MapFragment.customMapView(MapFragment.java:416) 
   at rojus.zvyjybos.com.zvejybosrojus2.map.MapFragment.onViewCreated(MapFragment.java:322) 
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086) 
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252) 
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742) 
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617) 
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:339) 
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:601) 
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1236) 
   at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6068) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2342) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2441) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:162) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5431) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:914) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:707) 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.
   at android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:34)
   at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:116)
   at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:110)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:916) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
   at rojus.zvyjybos.com.zvejybosrojus2.map.MapFragment.customMapView(MapFragment.java:416) 
   at rojus.zvyjybos.com.zvejybosrojus2.map.MapFragment.onViewCreated(MapFragment.java:322) 
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086) 
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252) 
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742) 
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617) 
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:339) 
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:601) 
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1236) 
   at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6068) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2342) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2441) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:162) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5431) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:914) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:707)
```

Comment: Please post your mainfiest file.

Comment: Add your androidmanifest

Comment: You need AppCompat ! add it to your build gradle com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0

Comment: I edited my answer also add appCompat however I still get the same exception

Comment: on the Styles AppTheme inherits from Theme.AppCompat or his childrens?

Comment: @ItzikSamara I add AppTheme code

Comment: @David try to clean up your code and re-run it.

Answer (score 4):

I just tried your code in a fresh project and it is working fine on my machine.
Make sure that `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'` is in your `build.gradle` file then do a rebuild and see if that helps. Also check your SDK manager to see if you have any old updates you haven't installed yet.

Answer (score 0):

Ok go to simple way.

first add Dependency to your build.gradle.

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

}

then open your XML file and add Floating action Button.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

then open your .java file and initialize the floating Button

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Click action
          // write you code here.
        }
    });
```

then Clean your project and run it.

I hope this Solution Help you.